# Does the following value partition cover the day of December 31st?

Tags: database, partitioning, dolphindb

Does the following value partition cover the day of December 31st?

```
create database "dfs://stock_day"
partitioned by RANGE(1991.01M + (0..30)*12), HASH([CHAR,2])
engine='OLAP',
atomic='TRANS',
chunkGranularity='TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

This database is partitioned by month, with the partition range covering all dates of the month, and for December, it will definitely include December 31st.
[image]